# UISearchBar Overlays UITableView - TableView Can't be moved

Tags: ios, arrays, uitableview, uisearchbar

I've got a TableView and a Search Bar set up and both work fine so far. The problem is that the UISearchBar overlays the first item of my TableView.

I cannot use XIB or storyboards in this project.

The definition and instantiation of the TableView is in a galaxy in a class (imported by a class I import...) far, far away -- not that easy to access.

I move (instantiate) the SearchBar on the screen with:

```
self.searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
[self.view addSubview:self.searchBar];
self.searchBar.delegate = self;
```

I  tried moving it to 0,-44 but then the screen does not stay at the SearchBar, it moves back down.

If I try to move the UITableView with:

```
self.tableView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 500);
```

it moves the SearchBar as well.

So let's say if I set the origin of the search bar at 0,0 and the origin of the table view at 0,44 I get a screen with (objects in this order):

- Grey Space with the height of a search bar/table view cell
- Search bar (still overlaying the first cell of my table view
- other cells

How can I solve this problem? I think the easiest way would be to add an empty object to my data array so the search bar overlays nothing of importance, but that would not be the nicest way of solving it.

Could anyone tell me how I can add/insert an object to an array and then copy another array into it, beginning with index 1, so my empty object stays in there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use contentInset property on your tableView. Just set the top inset to height of search bar.

```
self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(self.searchBar.frame.size.height, 0, 0, 0);
```

This should solve the issue.

Comment: Wow really nice solution, thank you! Could you please tell me how to make the screen start at 0,0,0,0, so you have to scroll up if you want to search? Like in the iPhone Music App when you wanna search for songs for example ;)

Comment: You could set search bar as tableHeaderView. If you'd like to have it initially hidden then you would need to adjust contentOffset of tableView a bit. This would work straight away but not exactly like in Music. To get achieve  that you would need to implement scrollViewDelegate method and detect whether to show search bar or hide it (if the contentOffset of tableView is smaller than searchBar.frame.size.height * 0.5f than show it, in other case hide it).

Comment: Alright thanks for the approach, I'll try to get it to work ;)!